# Creating a new Folder in Android Internal memory with different name after each run

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android app that collect data from a sensor. After each run it creates bunch of text files (e.g. A.txt, B.txt, C.txt, ...). My problem is after each run, all the text files are overwritten. I want to create a folder with a new name consisting current date and time of creation (e.g. 2020-02-07_11_41), then save all my text files into the new created folder.

I am sorry, I have very low knowledge of Android Studio. the following is part of my code that I want to modify:

```
if (b != null) {
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Random r = new Random();
                int subID = r.nextInt(200000);
                // set up subject data file
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", Locale.US);
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    String astring = df.format(c.getTime());
                    astring = astring.replace(":", "_");
                    afilename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/donor_" + astring + ".txt";
                    File scdatafile = new File(afilename);
                    FileOutputStream scdataout;
                    OutputStreamWriter scdatawriter;
                    if (scdatafile.exists())
                    {
                        scdatafile.delete();
                        scdatafile.createNewFile();
                        scdatafile.setReadable(true);
                        scdataout = new FileOutputStream(scdatafile);
                        scdatawriter = new OutputStreamWriter(scdataout);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        scdatafile.createNewFile();
                        scdatafile.setReadable(true);
                        scdataout = new FileOutputStream(scdatafile);
                        scdatawriter = new OutputStreamWriter(scdataout);
                    }
                    scdatawriter.append(" ");
                    scdatawriter.close();
                    scdataout.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // set up time data file
                try {
                    String scdatastring = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/sctimedata.txt";
                    File scdatafile = new File(scdatastring);
                    FileOutputStream scdataout;
                    OutputStreamWriter scdatawriter;
                    if (scdatafile.exists())
                    {
                        scdatafile.delete();
                        scdatafile.createNewFile();
                        scdatafile.setReadable(true);
                        scdataout = new FileOutputStream(scdatafile);
                        scdatawriter = new OutputStreamWriter(scdataout);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        scdatafile.createNewFile();
                        scdatafile.setReadable(true);
                        scdataout = new FileOutputStream(scdatafile);
                        scdatawriter = new OutputStreamWriter(scdataout);
                    }
                    scdatawriter.append(Integer.toString(subID) + "\t");
                    scdatawriter.close();
                    scdataout.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: At the exception catch do not continue with the code as if nothing has happened but return.

Comment: `scdatafile.createNewFile();`. Remove those statements. The file will be created by the new file output stream.

Comment: `scdatafile.setReadable(true);` Remove those too.

Comment: `scdatafile.delete();` Remove that statement too. And you do not have to check if the file already exists. Just the same code will do to overwrite or create new.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
String createFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/yourAppName" + currDate;
FileOutputStream scdataout;
OutputStreamWriter scdatawriter;

File createFolder = new File(creatFolderPath);
if(!createFolder.exists()){
    createFolder.mkdirs();
}

String outputName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + createFolderPath + "/donor_" + timeStamp + ".txt";

scdataout = new FileOutputStream(outputName);
scdatawriter = new OutputStreamWriter(scdataout);

...
//Your Code
```

I hope this can help you!

Thank You.

Comment: Check the return value of mkdirs(). Dont continue if it fails but display a toast for the user and stop.